# VichUploader uri_prefix not accounting for environment

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I am using the [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) in my project.
I am unable to get the download link (when using the `vich_file` form type) to take into account of the environment (notably *dev*). Which I want to do as I want to route the download function through a function.

My config is like;

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    twig:      true
    mappings:
        logo_image:
            uri_prefix:         /foo/image
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../app/private/images
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

And this generates the download uri of `http://example.com/foo/image/fubar.jpg`, regardless of the environment.
When in dev environment it should be `http://example.com/app_dev.php/foo/image/fubar.jpg`, or in test environment
`http://example.com/app_test.php/foo/image/fubar.jpg`

Comment: Why do you need this? These are static files, so they should not need to be handled by the frontend controller

Comment: @CarlosGranados because I want the images held above the web root so can only be accessed via a function where I can check credentials prior to serving the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a custom file namer class that has access to the router class.
In the config set the `uri_prefix` to **/**

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    twig:      true
    mappings:
        logo_image:
            uri_prefix:         /
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../app/private/images
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
            namer: my.namer.foo
```

Create a service namer class that return the full url with the route required (with parameter);

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\NamerInterface,
    Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\PropertyMapping;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
class MyNamer implements NamerInterface 
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router) 
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function name($foo, PropertyMapping $mapping) 
    {
        $router = $this->router->getContext();
        $full_url = $router->getHost();
        $full_url .= $router->getBaseUrl().'/';
        $full_url .= 'foo/logo/'.strtolower($foo->getName());
        return $full_url;
    }

}
```

Register it as a service;

```
services:
    my.namer.foo:
        class: AppBundle\Service\MyNamer
        arguments: ['@router']
        tags:
            - { name: namer }
```